# How do I get 'Run' on the Lubuntu Start menu to respond to the R key?

Tags: lubuntu, shortcut-keys, keyboard-accelerators

I'm using Lubuntu (15.04). The Start Menu has a 'Run' item for, well, running a command. When I open the menu, I want to press the R key and have the 'Run' item highlighted. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You do realize that you can start a program from the terminal.  Anyway, according to the Lubuntu documentation https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Keyboard#Create_New_Keyboard_shortcuts

> There is no automatic way to create new keyboard shortcuts or hotkeys
>   in lubuntu. You will either have to edit Lubuntu's openbox
>   configuration file (~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml) and edit, or
>   alternatively install xbindkeys.
>
> Obkey will edit the keyboard parts of your Openbox configuration file
>   for you. Download the .tar.gz and unarchive it. After unpacking the
>   tar.gz, open a command line in the new folder and run obkey like this:
>   ./obkey ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml Hint: back up your config
>   file. After saving the config file, you will need to run this command
>   to have openbox use the changed config: openbox --reconfigure
>
> For more information on the syntax of the configuration file, please
>   check out the official Openbox documentation on bindings. Note that
>   Super_R and Super_L are the two "Windows" keys when you just want to
>   use those keys. If you want to couple them with something else, use W-
>   plus whatever key you want to use.

Comment: http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Bindings This is the link to the openbox documentation.  Also lubuntu has the either windows key plus r to start the run dialog right away. Also there is alt f2 as another shortcut to start the run dialog So you do not need to open the menu to run. Alternatively with the  linked documentation you can create a shortcut to launch any program you want with that key.